# magnify effect on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

i have a navigation bar containing few links. i want the link to magnify(increase size) on mouse hover. i want other links to be in their respective position. i wrote code following code for this.

here is html

```
<ul>
<li> <a href="#">Link 1 </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#">Link 2 </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#">Link 3 </a> </li>
</ul>
```

css code:

```
a {
text-decoration:none;
font-size: 15px;
}
ul {
list-style-type:none;
} 
li {
display: inline;
padding-left: 50px;
}
```

and here is jquery for hover effect

```
 $(function(){
    $('a').hover(function(){
       $(this).css({'z-index':'1','font-size':'30px'});
    },
    function(){
       $(this).css({'z-index':'0','font-size':'15px'});
   });
});
```

here is the jsfiddle link for above [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m9tHb/)

i am not getting the desired effect. what did i miss? and how to use animate() in this zooming process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate very easily:

```
$(function(){
$('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({'z-index':'1','font-size':'30px'},50);
      },
      function(){
      $(this).animate({'z-index':'0','font-size':'15px'},50);
    });
});
```

e.g.:

http://jsfiddle.net/m9tHb/1/

What else don't you like about what you have at the moment?

Stop other links moving:

I am no CSS expert but by setting the width of the li elements and having them float left (stack up from the left) they will not move:

```
li {
    padding-left: 50px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m9tHb/3/

Though I am sure there are many ways to do it.. you just want to make sure that changing the size of the element will not affect anything else.. e.g. you could use absolute positioning.

P.S. just noticed that aligning the text in the li as centered makes it look nicer ;)

```
text-align:center;
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/m9tHb/4/

EDIT:  and example of absolute positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/m9tHb/5/

Comment: on mousehover i don't want other link to change its position. currently when i put mouse on link 1. the position of link 2 and link 3 are aloso affected

Comment: text-align:centre look much better. thanks for nice suggestion. can you tell me how to do this using absolute positioning.

Comment: ask another question and mark this one answered.. questions here are supposed to be specific they are not a door to getting free support! you need to try something first I cannot just explain absolute positioning to you when the question is not even about that. there is an example of it now in the answer but you would have to have a reason to use it over the float left technique